# How to Tune Hive Insert overwrite partition?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hdfs

I have written insert overwrite partition in hive to merge all the files in a partition into bigger file,

SQL:

```
SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
set hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=2560000000;
set hive.merge.mapredfiles=true;
set hive.merge.mapfiles =true;
SET mapreduce.max.split.size=256000000;
SET mapreduce.min.split.size=256000000;
SET mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.type =BLOCK;
SET hive.hadoop.supports.splittable.combineinputformat=true;
SET mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec=${v_compression_codec};

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE ${source_database}.${table_name} PARTITION (${line}) \n SELECT ${prepare_sel_columns} \n from ${source_database}.${table_name} \n WHERE ${partition_where_clause};\n"
```

With the above setting I am getting the compressed output but the time it takes to generate the output file is too long.

Even though it runs map only jobs , Takes much time.

Looking for any further setting from hive side to tune the Insert to run faster.

**Metrics.**

> 15 GB files ==> taking 10 min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
> SET mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize=512000000; 
> SET mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize=5120000000;
> SET mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.type =BLOCK;
> SET hive.hadoop.supports.splittable.combineinputformat=true;
> SET mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec=${v_compression_codec};
> ```

The above setting helped lot , The duration came down from 10 min to 1 min.

Comment: interesting, looks like you mainly just changed the split size settings

Comment: Yes that gives dramatic change in time , It seems I have used deprecated parameter , example 80 GB of data took 57 min before change in split parameter , After the change 800 GB took 35 Min. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it is a deprecated parameter it just isn't documented in the Hive wiki. I have been using the split size parameters as well for changing the number of mappers being used.